How to Extend Access Token Lifetime for Zoom Server-to-Server OAuth App in Production?
I've been watching videos and reading articles about creating Zoom meetings via API POST calls. However, I noticed that Zoom has changed its interface, and most of the resources are using the old method of integration. I've successfully built a server-to-server OAuth app that is working well, but at the top of my app, it says 'Intend to publish: No.' They never ask for your intent, nor do they let you change this option. I believe that 'Intend to publish: No' makes the access token lifetime only 1 hour.
Could someone guide me on how to build a server-to-server OAuth app with a production setup and a longer access token lifetime?
